# Reducing development time on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, agile

I am starting new medium size ASP.Net MVC project. There will be 50-60 tables. IE: employee tables(assigning training etc/) , basic warehouse management,. There wont be complicated workflows also.

I am looking for the ways to reduce my development time.

Scaffolding is a good starting point but hard to manage.

I could not decide about using AngularJS SPA or not, Using angular JS reduce the development time ? Or what is the advangates of using angular ?

What is your recommandations about reducing the development time on ASP.Net MVC projects, which ways are you using to building medium size applications.

Comment: If all you care about is development time, use only tools that you know.

Comment: Thanks, you are right but the application also needs to be easy to extend and modular. I dont mean need to be a form builder or any bpm . I mean i can easily add or remove new fields or tables. In my previous project i used devexpress and webforms to reduce time but know i could not manage to edit anything:(. Do you mean "write your project modular and extensible with the tools that you know" ? If yes, do you recommend any other framework to reduce this time?

Comment: Easy to extend and modular describes the manner in which you use the tool.  This can be achieved without unknown tools.  In my experience introducing a tool that is unknown will increase time because you are also having to learn basic things that would be natural in a tool you understand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your experience with MVC, but generally speaking, I'd suggest to use a UI Framework (like [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx), [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/MVC/get-started.xml) or [Aspnetawesome](http://aspnetawesome.com/)) because they offer plenty of example on how to organize your project. It definitly saves you time. Then which one you choose depends on your preference and budget. All 3 are good.

As for managing your data, just create a Domain project which will only contain your data access (probably repositories). For that project, it is no different from a normal C# project. You'll probably want to use Entity Framework, nHibernate or a similar ORM.

So to recap, divide your solution in at least 2 projects, one for the data and one for the UI, then use a UI framework for the MVC project and an ORM for the data access.

As for AngularJS, I would not focus on such tool unless you are really comfortable with MVC.

Pros:

- On the long term, you may save some time
- It is free
- It is well supported and seems to be there to last

Cons:

- If you are part (now or eventually) of a team, not all members will
  know that tool
- If you are comfortable with MVC, this will not save you significant time in my opinion. You don't become an MVC superstar
  because of it
- If you are not that comfortable with MVC, incorporating such tool is a bad idea. It is better to know a few tools but to use them
  properly than to poorly use many of them.